# C language-> Read a file to a dynamic array

Tags: c, dynamic, malloc, fread

So I have a file that as some text and I want my function to read that file and store it on an array. I did some code and when I print my dynamic array it prints crap values :< help.

```
char* read_message(char *filename) 
{   //gets the PATH of the txt file
    char *file_contents;
    long input_file_size;
    FILE *input_file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(input_file == NULL)                          
    { 
         return NULL;
    }
    fseek(input_file, 0, SEEK_END);     
    input_file_size = ftell(input_file);          
    rewind(input_file);                         
    file_contents = (char*)malloc(input_file_size+1 * (sizeof(char)));    
    fread(file_contents, input_file_size, 1, input_file);   
    printf("%s",file_contents);//----Prints crap--------
    fclose(input_file);
                                                  // returns the address to the array of strings
    return file_contents;       
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here, not an image of the code.

Comment: Please post code as text, not a picture of text or a link to a picture of text.  Also post your input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Just curious: Why did you allocate `input_file_size+1`? That `+1` in the end it's fundamental (see @dbush [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47359654/2436175)), but I wonder how did you come up with that, if you didn't know about the terminating character.

Comment: Well it was just a dumb moment, I actualy know about the terminating character the problem is when I tryed to put that at the end of the array with the size that the function ftell gave me it still did print crap output , Then I decided to use Watches and I saw that the file_contents had 3 extra crap values after reading all the file content and I dont know why, but I fixed it with this-> file_contents[input_file_size-3] = NULL;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read in the contents of the file into a char array.  At that point you do not yet have a string but an array of characters because there is no terminating null byte at the end.

When you then use `printf` to print this array, it reads the uninitialized byte at the end of the allocated memory segment (and possibly several bytes after it that are not part of allocated memory).  Reading uninitialized bytes invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Because calling `fread` does not add a terminating null byte after what was read, you need to do that yourself:

```
fread(file_contents, input_file_size, 1, input_file);
file_contents[input_file_size] = 0;
```

Comment: I would underline the importance of allocating `input_file_size+1`, which for some strange reason OP already did correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is immediately before the offending `printf()`.

```
file_contents = (char*)malloc(input_file_size+1 * (sizeof(char)));    
fread(file_contents, input_file_size, 1, input_file);   
printf("%s",file_contents);//----Prints crap--------
```

`fread()` does a binary read.   It does not add a zero terminator to `file_contents`.    If there is no character with value zero in the data read from file, then the `printf()` call has undefined behaviour.

Not also that `fread()` generally presumes that the file is opened for binary reading as well.   Your `open()` statement does not open the file in binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is :

You wrote :

```
malloc(input_file_size + 1 * (sizeof(char));
```

The priority goes to multiplication, so it is equivalent to :

```
malloc(input_file_size + (sizeof(char));
```

You should add parentheses.